# Как установить PyQt5 на windows 10?

Tags: python, pyqt5

ver = Python 3.8

Можете пошагово объяснить как установить этот модуль?

Comment: 1: на виндоус(pip install PyQt5)
2: что делать потом?

Comment: потом `pip install pyqt5-tools`

Comment: ошибку выдаёт
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt5-tools (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pyqt5-tools

Comment: попробуй через анаконду

Comment: значит для `Python 3.8` - `pyqt5-tools` еще не загрузили.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonicam это stackoverflow на русском, Поэтому комментарии нужно оставлять на русском языке